# How do I use `cp -R` to copy all files to a subfolder without copying the subfolder as well?

Tags: cp

I have an image folder which I am trying to copy into a subfolder of itself, so I can resize the images there.

It looks something like this:

```
$ ls
100x100                                 image1.png
image2.png                              image3.png
image4.png                              pic1.jpg
```

The issue I have is when I run the command `cp -R ./. 100x100`, I get an error, which basically says I can't keep adding 100x100 folders to themselves:

```
cp: 100x100/./100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/100x100/.DS_Store: name too long (not copied)
```

How do I use `cp -R` to copy files to a subfolder without also copying the subfolder?

Answer (score 2):

If your shell is `zsh` (likely if you're on macos):

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
cp -- {^,}100x100
```

Would expand to:

```
cp -- ^100x100 100x100
```

That is, copy all files but `100x100` into `100x100`.

To also copy hidden files:

```
cp -- ^100x100(D) 100x100
```

To only copy regular files (nor directories, symlinks, etc):

```
cp -- ^100x100(D.) 100x100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cp ./*.* ./100x100` *without* the `-R` option will copy all files in the directory into the `100x100` subdirectory without copying the directory into itself.

The `-R` option is for recursively copying all subdirectories into the target and should not be used if you do not want that to happen.

See `man cp` for more information on the options for the command and what they do.

Comment: `cp ./*.* ./100x100` without the `-R` option will copy all files _with a dot in the filename_... If you meant what you wrote you would use `cp ./* 100x100`

Comment: All image files with a type extension have a dot in the filename, while directories (and other, possibly broken, files) do not. That's why it works. ;)

Comment: My point is that `*.*` does not match _all files_, as you have written.

Comment: This wouldn't copy other directories either.